# category name is not show after save category` in backend in magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend, category-tree

> I create new sub category under default category after save category name is not show ?

[image]

help me please

Comment: In backend it is not showing or frontend??

Comment: i mention in my question

Comment: DID YOU GET ANY SOLUTIONS?

Comment: Not yet you  have same problem  ?

Comment: Yes I have same problem

Comment: Are you able to edit other categories?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: Please run reindexing command

Comment: not working after reindexing command

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I have found one solution for this. It's working fine for me.

For the category name you need to check your "Mysql Table => catalog_eav_attribute".

In This Table you need check two entry one for Attribute id 45 and another is 46.

If you have not found This then you need manualy Insert both of that.

Need to add three colum first is (attribute_id => 'Attributeid ex. 45 and 46', is_visible => 'Visitbility default ex. 1', search_weight => 'default ex. 1').

[image]

After that check.