# Category not saving in back end after Migration from 1.9.3.2 to 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, migration

I have migrated magento from 1.9.3.2 to 2.2.3.

I don't have more product but still i am not able to save category changes in magento 2.

After Press Save buttton "You saved the category." message displays but not changes are saved, even category name is not changing.

Please anyone knowing how to resolve this issue then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see my answer it might be helpful to you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205886/category-name-is-not-show-after-save-category-in-backend-in-magento-2/229928#229928

Comment: Hello There, I have you tried clearing your cache after saving? Or is your cache turned on?

Comment: i have disabled cache. also tried to clean and flush cache via CLI. But, still same problem can not change any category data.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav i have also tried your answer but did not work for me. I have already both the attribute ids in database.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. Any solution to this.. @MayankRanpara ??

Comment: @UsmanYousaf I could not find a specific solution to this problem. But, I remigrated database for older version to newer version with some configuration changes and its working now. Try to remigrate without interrupt for any errors.

Comment: @UsmanYousaf I could not find a specific solution to this problem. But, I remigrated database for older version to newer version with some configuration changes and its working now. Try to remigrate without interrupt for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a specific solution to this problem. But, I remigrated database for older version to newer version with some configuration changes and its working now. Try to remigrate without interrupt for any errors.